# Update users in realtime (Web)

Tags: php, mysql, web

I want to make an application where users use their own computer together with a host, the host click ”Start” and then there shall automatically show a button on all users computers at the same time. Then the first person who click the button will win. I want this to happen in the browser, but I dont know wich technology to use. I already know PHP and mysql, but I dont know anyway to update users computers in realtime. Wich technology would be the best choice to make this happen?

Comment: I think you might look into [web sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here is basically web sockets, likely with a pub/sub layer on top. It can be done relatively simply with a decent Javascript and server-side library. PHP isn't the ideal language for this, but it works just fine with the right tools. [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world) is a decent PHP web socket server implementation, and [Autobahn|JS](http://autobahn.ws) a decent client-side library (note: at the time of writing the latest Autobahn|JS WAMP implementation is incompatible with the older WAMP implementation of Ratchet, use [Autobahn|JS WAMP v1](http://autobahn.ws/js/reference_wampv1.html)). Follow the Ratchet tutorial, then expand into setting up a pub/sub server as described [here](http://socketo.me/docs/push) (you don't need the ZeroMQ components, you'll be triggering events by a publish action instead of an external ZeroMQ event).

That's a 30,000 foot overview, go forth and try it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I received many great answers, but I think this will be the best solution. I want to develop from scratch and I want to learn something, so this seems like the best approach for me.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Pusher.com has the ideal solution for this. You can send events, listen to these events and then respond accordingly. They have a free plan which I think is way more than you will probably need. Pusher works with JavaScript and it's extremely simple to get started

I suggest reading up on the documentation at pusher.com/docs